# Why do I have log-entries in `/var/log/ufw.log` while my laptop was in standby?

Tags: network-interface, laptop, ufw

While debugging a network related issue I found these entries in `/var/log/ufw.log`:

```bash
$ tail -f /var/log/ufw.log
Jun 22 00:07:55 ierbert2 kernel: [217764.254528] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp59s0 OUT= MAC=9c:b6:d0:c5:be:85:dc:a6:32:7d:e2:72:08:00 SRC=192.168.9.116 DST=192.168.9.115 LEN=351 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=1206 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=38646 DPT=48498 LEN=331 
Jun 22 00:07:56 ierbert2 kernel: [217765.247871] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp59s0 OUT= MAC=9c:b6:d0:c5:be:85:dc:a6:32:7d:e2:72:08:00 SRC=192.168.9.116 DST=192.168.9.115 LEN=351 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=1430 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=38646 DPT=52538 LEN=331 
Jun 22 00:07:56 ierbert2 kernel: [217765.258617] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp59s0 OUT= MAC=9c:b6:d0:c5:be:85:dc:a6:32:7d:e2:72:08:00 SRC=192.168.9.116 DST=192.168.9.115 LEN=351 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=1431 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=38646 DPT=48498 LEN=331 
Jun 22 00:07:57 ierbert2 kernel: [217766.247642] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp59s0 OUT= MAC=9c:b6:d0:c5:be:85:dc:a6:32:7d:e2:72:08:00 SRC=192.168.9.116 DST=192.168.9.115 LEN=351 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=1558 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=38646 DPT=52538 LEN=331 
Jun 22 00:09:02 ierbert2 kernel: [217831.408683] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp59s0 OUT= MAC=9c:b6:d0:c5:be:85:dc:a6:32:7d:e2:72:08:00 SRC=192.168.9.116 DST=192.168.9.115 LEN=351 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=2002 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=38646 DPT=35295 LEN=331 
Jun 22 00:09:55 ierbert2 kernel: [217884.249669] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp59s0 OUT= MAC=9c:b6:d0:c5:be:85:dc:a6:32:7d:e2:72:08:00 SRC=192.168.9.116 DST=192.168.9.115 LEN=351 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=7035 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=38646 DPT=52618 LEN=331 
Jun 22 00:09:55 ierbert2 kernel: [217884.258993] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp59s0 OUT= MAC=9c:b6:d0:c5:be:85:dc:a6:32:7d:e2:72:08:00 SRC=192.168.9.116 DST=192.168.9.115 LEN=351 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=7037 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=38646 DPT=58310 LEN=331 
Jun 22 00:09:56 ierbert2 kernel: [217885.251707] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp59s0 OUT= MAC=9c:b6:d0:c5:be:85:dc:a6:32:7d:e2:72:08:00 SRC=192.168.9.116 DST=192.168.9.115 LEN=351 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=7284 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=38646 DPT=52618 LEN=331 
Jun 22 00:09:56 ierbert2 kernel: [217885.260073] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp59s0 OUT= MAC=9c:b6:d0:c5:be:85:dc:a6:32:7d:e2:72:08:00 SRC=192.168.9.116 DST=192.168.9.115 LEN=351 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=7285 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=38646 DPT=58310 LEN=331
```

My laptop was in standby mode last night, and the system time is correct. I noticed that there are entries in the log file during that time.

How is it possible to have log entries recorded when the PC was supposedly in standby?

Comment: I do not know, but remember that when waking up a laptop, the clock is still set at the time it was put to sleep. It takes a few seconds to adjust. Could that explain what you see?